# CodeIgniter: "Unable to load the requested class"

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoloader

On my WAMP box, I did the following:

1. Added a file called /application/libraries/Foo.php
2. Foo.php is a class, and it's name is `Foo`
3. In /application/config/autoload.php, I added `$autoload['libraries'] = array('foo');`

Everything works fine. When I upload to my LAMP box, I get the following error:

`Unable to load the requested class: foo`

Permission of /application/libraries/Foo.php is 0755. Owner is the same as the rest of the CI files. Taking `foo` out from autoload makes the problem go away.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Windows, capitalization in paths doesn't matter.  In Linux it does.

When you autoload, use "Foo" not "foo".

I believe that will do the trick.

I think it works when you take it out of autoloading because codeigniter is smart enough to figure out the capitalization in the path and classes are case independent in php.

Comment: i think there are some mistrakes in the code ignitors docs about case

Comment: Had the same issue. In autoload I had 'oauth2', but changed to 'OAuth2' and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: in Linux what is FOO ? Is that model ? or Class or controller of view or something else ? Please be specific.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when deploying from OSx on my local to my Linux live site.

It ran fine on OSx, but on Linux I was getting:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: Ckeditor
```

The problem was that Linux paths are apparently case-sensitive so I had to rename my library files from "ckeditor.php" to "CKEditor.php".

I also changed my load call to match the capitalization:

```
$this->load->library('CKEditor');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a linux server for your application then it is necessary to use lowercase file name and class name to avoid this issue.

Ex.

Filename: csvsample.php

```
class csvsample {

}
```